# Combining popup info from overlapping polygons in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: polygon, geojson, popup, mapbox-gl-js

I've tried several solutions, but I'm having trouble populating a popup with information from overlapping polygons. When there are polygons that overlap, I want to drill down and pull the names from all polygons at the click point. Any help on this would be awesome.

```
 // When a click event occurs on a feature in the states layer, open a popup at the 
location of the click, with description HTML from its properties.


map.on('click', 'testlayer', function (e) {
    new mapboxgl.Popup()
        .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
        .setHTML(e.features[0].properties.name)
        .addTo(map);
});
```

[The jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/mfrans/f2kLw46x/8/)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within your map.on('click') callback, `e.features` is an array of all features from `testlayer` at the point clicked.

So instead of only choosing the first in your popup, you can display all values like this:

```js
map.on('click', 'testlayer', function (e) {
    new mapboxgl.Popup()
        .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
        .setHTML(e.features.map(function(feature) { return feature.properties.name; }).join(', '))
        .addTo(map);
});
```

This extracts the `name` property from each feature and joins them into a  string separated by `,`.

Comment: Perfect... exactly what I was looking for.