# Combining popup info from overlapping polygons in Mapbox Studio?

Tags: mapbox, popup, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-studio

I'm trying to display popup information from overlapping polygons similar to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253694/combining-popup-info-from-overlapping-polygons-in-mapbox-gl-js%7D), but instead of a click, I'm using the mouse over to identify my popup. In areas that have overlapping polygons, I'd like to display the Name and Description from all polygons. I'm trying to incorporate the correct answer to my particular case, but I'm just not understanding the logic.

**My Original Code**

```
   //change info window on hover
          map.on('mousemove', function(e) {
          var neighborhood = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
            layers: ['Neighborhood_layer']
          });

          if (neighborhood.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById('pd').innerHTML = 
            "<p><em>Name: " + neighborhood[0].properties.Name +
            "<p><em>Name: " + neighborhood[0].properties.Description +
            "</em></p>";
          } else {
            document.getElementById('pd').innerHTML = '<p>Hover over a Neighborhood</p>';
          }
        });
      });
```

**My Attempt**

```
  //change info window on hover
      map.on('mousemove', function(e) {
      var neighborhood = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
        layers: ['Neighborhood_layer']
 setHTML(e.features.map(function(neighborhood) { return feature.properties.Name; }).join(', '))
 setHTML(e.features.map(function(neighborhood) { return feature.properties.Description; }).join(', '))
      });

      if (neighborhood.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById('pd').innerHTML = 
        "<p><em>Name: " + neighborhood[0].properties.Name +
        "<p><em>Name: " + neighborhood[0].properties.Description +
        "</em></p>";
      } else {
        document.getElementById('pd').innerHTML = '<p>Hover over a Neighborhood</p>';

    });
  });
```

**UPDATED Attempt**
I'm not understanding the logic, but if I change `neighborhood [0]` to `neighborhood [1]`, I'm able to identify most overlapping features but not all...

```
  //change info window on hover
      map.on('mousemove', function(e) {
      var neighborhood = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
        layers: ['Neighborhood_layer']
 setHTML(e.features.map(function(neighborhood) { return feature.properties.Name; }).join(', '))
 setHTML(e.features.map(function(neighborhood) { return feature.properties.Description; }).join(', '))
      });

      if (neighborhood.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById('pd').innerHTML = 
        "<p><em>Name: " + neighborhood[1].properties.Name +
        "<p><em>Name: " + neighborhood[1].properties.Description +
        "</em></p>";
      } else {
        document.getElementById('pd').innerHTML = '<p>Hover over a Neighborhood</p>';

    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

neighbourhood is an Array of features under the mouse, so where you are grabbing the first only with `neighbourhood[0]` you can iterate over or concatenate.

Comment: Andrew, thank you so much for responding!!  If I'm understanding you correctly, the neighborhood[0] only grabs the first one.  Now how would I change that to include the other overlapping features? Sorry, I'm new to this!

Comment: `neighbourhood` is an *array*, that is a collection of things. You can get the first item in the array by *indexing* it, like this: `neighbourhood[0]`. `neighbourhood[1]` gets you the next item. Your popup logic currently displays a *single item*. You need to make new logic that knows what to do with a *collection* of items, i.e. multiple items, most likely using a `for` loop to do something with *each* item in turn.